# How to run gif as php file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to display **Access Denied** page when someone access to my gif link `localhost/img/logo.gif` and display the real images and execute php script when I get some parameter in the url, like: `localhost/img/logo.gif?myname=test`

I've tried add this to `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule logo.GIF http://127.0.0.1/img/test.php [NC]
```

I don't know what should I write in `test.php`.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `.htaccess` rules are working correctly then in your `test.php` file you would have something like this:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['myname']) && $_GET['myname'] == 'test')
{
    header('Content-type: image/gif', TRUE);
    echo file_get_contents('logo.gif');
}
else
{
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden', TRUE);
    echo '<h1>Access Denied</h1>';
}
die();
```

Comment: it's work but the url change to `localhost\img\test.php` and gif work . It's possible to keep it like this `localhost\img\logo.GIF`

Comment: Tey to access logo.GIF - it should behave as you like. But remember the .htaccess file must be in the same directory.

Comment: Yeah i know it's same directory but Sir i real i didn't understand whta i should to make url `localhost\img\logo.gif`

Comment: This becomes a new question - about htaccess. If you access http://localhost/img/logo.GIF it should say access denied. You would need to modify the htaccess to pass over the GET parameters.

Comment: yeah that's it so what i should modify in htaccess file to make it work sir thank you

Comment: David , please if you had any idea how i  do that because that what i real i want thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If the redirect rule is working properly and you're not using a PHP framework you can just write any PHP script.

I'm not sure how proficient you are with PHP, but you can start with something like this to make sure it's working, and iterate from there:

```
<?php
  $imagePath = 'path/to/other/image.file';
?>

<head><title>GIF Redirect Page</title></head>

<body>
   <h1>Show correct image</h1>
   <img src="<?php echo $imagePath; ?>" />
</body>
```

Comment: Not this what i mean